# How to create a polygon from the union of the areas formed by a circle running in a line formed by two geographic points?

Tags: postgis

How can I create a polygon like in the right side of the picture from a line formed by two geographic points like in the left side of the picture in PostGIS?
[image: Question example]

I was thinking in calculating the area by two ways:
1) The polygon is the union of the area of all infinite circles with an radius x running inside the line formed by the two geographic points
2) The area of a rectangle centered in the line with a x*2 width united with the two circles of radius x, one centered in the top and the other in the bottom geographic points.
The points are geographic points (like -72.1235 42.3521) and I like the radius of the circle to be informed in meters.

Comment: What about making a linear feature from the two points and buffering the line? (I don't know postgis, so can't give you the steps)

Comment: @mkennedy YES! "Line buffer" was the name I was searching for... I will look into that.

Comment: Are you sure you need to *create* the buffer, or do you actually need to test against items being inside/outside a buffer *distance* of a given line? In most cases, you're far better off using `ST_DWithin()` which efficiently handles the latter case. Welcome to GIS SE :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see my solution:
first you need to create line from your points: `ST_MakeLine(geometry geom1, geometry geom2);`
http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html

And than you need to create a buffer around the line, but because you are in degree coordinate system (probably wgs84) you should transform the line into another coordinate system (meter based). The query looks like this: `ST_BUFFER(ST_TRANSFORM(the_line_geom,3857),100)`
where the 3857 is the new coordinate system (WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator), but you should use your country coordinate system to get a better solution. The 100 is the buffer distance in meter.